# EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and could not initialize MongoTemplate bean

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test, spring-mongodb

I just add MongoDB configuration to the existing Spring Boot application, some test class has `@SpringBootTest` annotation, and those classes throw exceptions that says I need to define embedded MongoDB version like below

`...Set the spring.mongodb.embedded.version property...`

I set this on `test/resources/application.properties` to 4.4 version.

Now It is starts to throw below exception

```
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path resource 

[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedMongoServer' defined in class path resource 

[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/embedded/EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'embeddedMongoServer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedMongoConfiguration' defined in class path resource 

[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/embedded/EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.config.MongodConfig]: Factory method 'embeddedMongoConfiguration' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
```

using Spring Boot 2.7.10
How to make it work with @SpringBootTest annotation?

Answer (score 0):

it is worked with these properties, downgrade embedded-mongo from 4.4 and provide complete uri

```
spring.mongodb.embedded.version=3.6.5
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/yourDB
```